# Writing and debugging JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have tried to port my HTML5 + JS application to Windows Phone 8 via Visual Studio, but have failed, and while it feels the problems I have should be very common, I have not managed to find solutions.

1. In VisualStudio Express 2012, I made a new HTML5 project. It is still under the C# category. When adding JavaScript to the index.html file, I get a lot of errors, such as using && in an if-statement and in a normal for-loop such as ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) it throws an error at the second i. It seems to me it just doesn't parse JavaScript (there is no syntax highlighting on that part), I have seen videos where they make new JavaScript files too, but I can't do that either.

If I run the application, it seems to execute JS (such as alerts), but breaks at the first usage of jQuery (I have included it).

1. In VisualStudio Express 2013, I have read that it supports Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 applications, however, I can only make ones for Windows Phone 8.1. It is not possible to change, and therefore does not execute on my Lumia 920 which has yet to get the upgrade.

I am very unfamiliar with the whole Visual Studio package as well as other Windows tools (I mostly write Java, JavaScript, PHP, HTML e.t.c. in Notepad++, Eclipse, Dreamweaver), and after a couple days of fighting with it and barely making any progress, I hope someone here can help. Sorry for the long wall of text.

EDIT: I did not initally have a DOCTYPE defined, adding  fixed the jQuery issue. Still, it throws an error on every for loop and similar, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      var x = i;
    }
</script>
```

Throws the following error, with the '<' sign marked:

**Illegal syntax. Expecting valid start name character.**

Comment: Double-check the extension of the file you are adding. Make sure it ends in `.js`.  You can use the `F2` key to rename existing files and change the extension, if you need to.

Comment: At the moment I have it in an HTML-file inside script-tags, is there any particular reason this wouldn't work in Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `DOCTYPE` you are using and the format of your `script` tag?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Added. Still feels to me that I just does not read it as JS, therefore the errors. The errors in the emulator itself (still works very poorly) might be because of different reasons, but I am not sure how I can see them since it works fine in both IE and Chrome.

Comment: Add a 4.01 strict or HTML5 doctype.  It is *acting* like you have (or it is assuming) an XHTML doctype.   http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: And remember, the DOCTYPE has to be the first non-whitespace thing ther.

Comment: @jeremy Yeah, I changed it to the 4.01 strict, first there was a warning about 'Root element must match doctype', so I changed the <html> tag to <HTML>. The warning disappeared, but same issues as before, apart from a new "The operation has timed out" error message appearing at line 1.

EDIT: Also, realized the full name of the software is "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone"

Comment: @jeremy I tried adding a script-tag in a new, blank project (apart from the template), and at least the JS code is executed when I run it in the emulator, however, Visual Studio still throws errors.

Comment: Since it does not have JavaScript syntax highlighting, I can't choose to make a new JavaScript file, when I go to DEBUG > Windows there is no JavaScript Console option (as I read about somewhere). I guess VS Expres 2012 for Windows Phone just does not have these features, somehow...